# Проблема с записью данных изображения в бд Yii2

Tags: yii2, yii

Использую costa-rico\yii2images, и при записе данных в бд создается папка с именем `News/NewsArray`, а в таблицу не чего не сохраняется, хотя изображение загружается

```
public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model = new News();
        $category = Category::find()->where(['status' => self::STATUS_ACITVE])->all();
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
            $model->image = $this->uploadImage($model);
            debug($model->attachImage($model->image));die();
            $r = $model->attachImage($model->image);
            debug($r);die();
            @unlink($model->image);
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
        }

        return $this->render('create', ['model' => $model, 'category' => $category]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я понимаю это расширение не занимается сохранением файла картинки.
Нужно сохранить файл, а затем привязывать к новостям:

```
$model->imageFile = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'imageFile');
$fileName = 'uploads/' . $this->imageFile->baseName . '.' . $this->imageFile->extension;
$model->imageFile->saveAs($fileName);
```

См. https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/ru/input-file-upload

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/308185)

Comment: Ок, спасибо за замечание